# Creating a Python .exe file: py2exe invalid image error

Tags: python, wxpython, py2exe

I want to create a `.exe` file. I'm using Python 2.7.3 with wxPython for the GUI. I've installed `py2exe` for Python 2.7 and tried to create a `.exe` file following the tutorial at http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

When I try to run my created `.exe` file, I get following error:

```
File "wx\_gdi.pyc",line823, in BitmapFromImage wx._core.PyAssertionError: 
C++ assertion "image.OK()" failed at ..\..\src\msw\bitmap.cpp(802) in 
wxBitmap::CreateFromImage(): invalid image
```

So I looked into my code and the following line is causing the problem:

```
self.bmpSun = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.BitmapFromImage(wx.Image('images/sun.gif', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)), pos = (0,0))
```

When I browse to the source folder and run the `main.py` file myself, my app runs fine. I haven't found any help online so far. Can anybody solve this problem/suggest reliable alternatives for `py2exe`? Thank you.

Comment: Ive had lots of luck with innosetup and pyinstaller ... (and i use wx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line that errors out is looking for an image in the `Images` folder. That's a path relative to the `.exe` file created by `py2exe`.  So you need to be sure that that folder exists in correct position relative to the exe, and that it is populated with the images you are going to use.  You can do this 2 ways.  Either copy the folder to where the exe will reside, or use the `data_files` keyword arg in the script that makes the `.exe`.  Here's the pertinent part of one of my setup scripts, showing a `data_files` list of tuples and use of the `data_files` keyword arg later:

```
data_files = [('Images', glob('Images/*.*')),
                            ]

includes = ['win32com.decimal_23', 'datetime']

excludes = ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'curses',  'pywin.debugger',
            'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs', 'tcl',
            'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter', 'unittest']
packages = []

dll_excludes = ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll', 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 'tcl84.dll',
                'tk84.dll','MSVCP90.dll']

setup(
    data_files = data_files,
    options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 2,
                          "optimize": 2,
                          "includes": includes,
                          "excludes": excludes,
                          "packages": packages,
                          "dll_excludes": dll_excludes,
                          "bundle_files": 1,
                          "dist_dir": "dist",
                          "xref": False,
                          "skip_archive": False,
                          "ascii": False,
                          "custom_boot_script": '',
                         }
              },
    zipfile = None,
    windows = [filename]
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! I never thought I had to replace the images folder if it worked within my IDE. I copied the images one folder down into the dist folder and everything works ok no!