# Include images in py2exe?

Tags: wxpython, py2exe

I've got a wxPython application that uses wx.Bitmap and a few bitmap buttons. Is there a way to include these images so the exe runs properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a data_files element in your setup.py file: [Creating a Python .exe file: py2exe invalid image error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829261/creating-a-python-exe-file-py2exe-invalid-image-error)

Alternatively, you can use py2exe or something similar (PyInstaller, bbfreeze, cx_freeze) to create the Python exe and then use something like Inno Setup to bundle up everything into a nice installer.